# Malloc space for a pointer of array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I need to work upon a variable number of fixed-size arrays. More specifically, N points in a K-dimensional space, where I know K beforehand, but I don't know N at compile time.
So I want to use a pointer to the fixed-size array, and allocate space for N K-dimensional points at runtime.

In C, I can allocate the said pointer with malloc. Example `test.c` below, where dimension is 3 for simplicity:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIMENSIONS  3

typedef float PointKDimensions[DIMENSIONS];

void do_stuff( int num_points){
  PointKDimensions *points;
  points = malloc(num_points * sizeof(PointKDimensions));
  points[5][0] = 0;    // set value to 6th point, first dimension
  points[5][1] = 1.0;  // to second dimension
  points[5][2] = 3.14; // to third dimension
  return;
}

int main(){
    do_stuff(10); // at run-time I find out I have 10 points to handle
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile this with `gcc test.c` without errors, and run without segmentation faults.

However, if I try to achieve the same behavior with C++ `mv test.c test.cpp`, followed by `g++ test.cpp`, I get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void do_stuff(int)’:
test.cpp:10:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float (*)[3]’ [-fpermissive]
10 |   points = malloc(num_points * sizeof(float) * DIMENSIONS);
   |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   |                  |
   |                  void*
```

Searching up, I found that C++ does not do implicit conversions for malloc, so I changed the malloc to:

```
 points = (float*) malloc(num_points * sizeof(float) * DIMENSIONS);
```

And then the error becomes:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void do_stuff(int)’:
test.cpp:10:12: error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘float (*)[3]’ in assignment
   10 |   points = (float*) malloc(num_points * sizeof(float) * DIMENSIONS);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            |
      |            float*
```

But I could not find a way to do the appropriate cast/conversion to solve this error. E.g., `(float**)` is also not the same as `float(*)[3]`.

Any suggestions on how to allocate space for a pointer to fixed-sized arrays in C++?

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++.  If you want a run time sized array, use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the result of `malloc` as `PointKDimensions*` not as a `float*`:

```
typedef float PointKDimensions[DIMENSIONS];

void do_stuff( int num_points){
  PointKDimensions *points;
  points = (PointKDimensions*)malloc(num_points * sizeof(PointKDimensions));
  points[5][0] = 0;    // set value to 6th point, first dimension
  points[5][1] = 1.0;  // to second dimension
  points[5][2] = 3.14; // to third dimension
  return;
}
```

Or better, use C++'s built-in container for dynamically sized arrays, `std::vector`:

```
vector<vector<float>> points;

void do_stuff( int num_points){
  points.resize(num_points, vector<float>(k)); // assuming k = number of dimensions.
  points[5][0] = 0;    // set value to 6th point, first dimension
  points[5][1] = 1.0;  // to second dimension
  points[5][2] = 3.14; // to third dimension
  return;
}
```

Comment: We know the number of dimensions for the inner array, so nested `vector`s is not appropriate here. Has the potential to slows the program down dramatically.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Also, the point mentioned by @user4581301 is what I was trying to leverage when keeping the information about the known size. I know a bit about std containers, they are more flexible and safe, but my target is a scientific application (forgot to mention), so keeping things as raw as possible was intended. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @exepe combine this answer with Erdal's and you'll have a very robust and efficient solution.

Comment: @user4581301 I wanted to write something similar. If you want it to be as raw as possible, `std::vector` as point is not the best choice, `std::array` is better suited for that. But what you were pointing out all the time, instead of `malloc` a `std::vector` is the appropriate container for that, long story short: `std::vector<std::array<TYPE, DIM>>`

Comment: @user4581301 yes, already did, thanks for the suggestion. As I can only pick one correct answer I choose this one because it was a direct solution to the problem, but I had upvoted Erdal's answer as well as it was also helpful. It's my first ever question in the StackOverflow community so I hope I did everything properly.

Comment: @exepe The goal is to help each other out. As long as nobody gives you a hint, that you did something wrong, don't let that trouble you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [std:array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for that.

e.g.

```
#include <array>

inline constexpr const size_t DIMENSIONS = 3;
using PointKDimensions = std::array<float, DIMENSIONS>;
```

Comment: While I largely agree with the answer, I suspect the asker has some reason they want to get the storage from the freestore rather than an automatic allocation.

Comment: And reading over the question again, I can see what the reason is: `num_points` is not a fixed value. The answer skips over how to correctly use `malloc`  and a cast, and the answer to that bit is "Don't. Use a `std::vector`."

Comment: @user4581301 _std::array is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member._ The question at the end is: _Any suggestions on how to allocate space for a pointer to fixed-sized arrays in C++?_ We do have a fixed size array; with the type `float`, `PointKDimensions` is trivially copyable, therefore save for malloc, memcpy and co.

Comment: @user4581301 One thing i've learned migrating from C to C++ was, pointer and arrays are better wrapped into appropriate classes.

Comment: Agree 100%. My point is the asker is little better off when they try to allocate `num_points` `std::arrays` than they were trying to allocate `num_points` `float [DIMENSIONS]`s. `std::vector<PointKDimensions> points(num_points);` makes almost all of the dynamic allocation and casting issues go away.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand. Full ack.